# Синхронизация потоков через Семафоры C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность

> «Библиотека». Первый поток моделирует взятие книги читателем. Второй
>   поток моделирует сдачу книги. Количество книг в библиотеке ограничено.
>   Потоки находятся в разных процессах.

Подскажите, как должно быть? 
Делаю так:

```
 class Program
    {
        static Semaphore semaphoreObj = new Semaphore(4, 5, "my_semaphore");

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {  
            Process.Start(@"C:\visual studio 2015_Projects\4p\bin\Debug\4p.exe");
            Thread.Sleep(133);
            Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Поток 1";
            while (true)
                Count();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public static void Count()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                semaphoreObj.WaitOne();
                int el;
                using (FileStream fsr = new FileStream(@"C:\books.txt", FileMode.Open))
                using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fsr)) el = br.ReadInt32();
                using (FileStream fsr1 = new FileStream(@"C:\books.txt", FileMode.Open))
                using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fsr1))
                {
                    el -= 1;
                    bw.Write(el);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                int f = semaphoreObj.Release();
                Console.WriteLine("{0} взял книгу. Книг {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name, f);
            }

        }
    }

}
```

И так:

```
    class Program
    {
        static Semaphore semaphoreObj;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             semaphoreObj = Semaphore.OpenExisting("my_semaphore");
            Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Поток 2";
           while (true)            
                Count();

              Console.ReadLine();
        }
        public static void Count()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            {
                semaphoreObj.WaitOne();
                int el;
                using (FileStream fsr = new FileStream(@"C:\books.txt", FileMode.Open))
                using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fsr)) el = br.ReadInt32();
                using (FileStream fsr1 = new FileStream(@"C:\books.txt", FileMode.Open))
                using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fsr1))
                {
                    el += 1;
                    bw.Write(el);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(2500);
                int f=semaphoreObj.Release();
                Console.WriteLine("{0} сдал книгу. Книг {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name, f);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Получается, что число книг не изменяется. В чем проблема не могу понять...

Comment: Эээээ... А зачем у вас `Process.Start`? Вам же нужно два потока, а не два процесса?

Comment: Два потока в двух разных процессах

Comment: Подсказка: ваш код чтения файлов нерабочий.

Comment: @Marchosias: В условии ничего не сказано про _процессы_. Вы уверены, что нужны именно процессы, а не потоки?

Comment: @andreycha, код чтения фалов для того, чтобы поток хоть что-то делал, а не просто спал

Comment: @VladD, в задании надо чтобы, было в разных процессах, а то соответственно и разные потоки

Comment: @Marchosias: Тогда внесите это в вопрос. Текст задания в вопросе не содержит ни слова о процессах.

Answer (score 0):

```
 class Program
{
    static Semaphore semaphoreObj = new Semaphore(4, 5);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {  

        Process.Start(@"C:\visual studio 2015_Projects\4p\bin\Debug\4p.exe");
        Thread.Sleep(133);
        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Поток 1";
        while (true)
            Count();

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static async void Count()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
        await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
        try
        {

            int el;
            using (FileStream fsr = new FileStream(@"C:\books.txt", FileMode.Open))
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fsr)) el = br.ReadInt32();
            using (FileStream fsr1 = new FileStream(@"C:\books.txt", FileMode.Open))
            using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(fsr1))
            {
                el -= 1;
                bw.Write(el);
            }
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
             }
        catch { }
        finally
        {
            semaphoreSlim.Release();
        }
            Console.WriteLine("{0} взял книгу. Книг {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.Name, f);
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Старайтесь хоть как-то комментировать код - что вы поменяли в коде задавшего вопрос и на что это повлияло? Самую суть хотя бы.